# How can I control access to hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a HDP 2.4 installed on my cluster.
Let's say, I have a table (Table_1) with sensitive columns. I can create a view (V_Table_1) containing only non-sensitive data, create policies in Ranger and grant access to either Table_1 or V_Table_1.
It will work using Beeline.
But it will not work if someone has direct access to hdfs or even if one uses Spark.

Is there any way (or best practices) to control access to data stored on hdfs?

Will Apache Atlas in HPD 2.6 do the job?

Answer (score 0):

First, the only true way to ensure security in Hadoop is to enable Kerberos. Then audit any and all HDFS actions against your sensitive data.

> But it will not work if someone has direct access to hdfs or even if one uses Spark

If you have users impersonating others via `HADOOP_USER_NAME`, then they might be able to access things, but HDFS ACLs should be able to prevent that.

Otherwise, Ranger is injecting code into the Hive driver (maybe Spark too) to mask/hide particular columns. If you want to prevent direct HDFS access, you'll need to prevent SSH access to Hadoop server or not distribute keytabs for external client access for untrusted parties

I'm not completely sure the function of Atlas

Comment: I do have Kerberos authentication. You said 'HDFS ACLs yould be able to prevent that'. But ACLs wold ok database/table level? In my question, I'm asking about access on column level. I want people to have access to the table (hdfs level granted) but no access to particular columns...

Comment: I believe that is only tracable at the level of Ranger, not Filesystem ACLs. I was mostly referring to entire directories.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to create Hive views. Ranger supports column level security rules so you can block sensitives columns to non authorized users, or even better replace values by masks (eg: "John Doe" becomes "xxxxxxxx")

There is no way to block the access to HDFS file(s) containing the data otherwise Hive won't be able to read it. However you should block HDFS APIs to non authorised users! So no SSH on edge nodes, no Kerberos keytab provided, and access to HIVE through KNOX and LDAP authentication.